# SVG.js How to update pattern scale and position?

Tags: drawing, svg.js

Hi I'm trying to fill a polygon with a pattern here https://codesandbox.io/s/pmqv6vxvw0 (watch the HelloWorld.vue the drawPath() and anymPath() there)

Looks like it has the only option to update element, not the pattern's parameter [enter link description here](https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/elements/#pattern-update)

Is there a way to change the scale as well?

And the pattern alignment, is it possible to move the pattern into the middle of the container?

Comment: Please break your question down to the actual problem. Nobody wants to dig through your code to understand what your issue is. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without any extra framework would be best.

Comment: Excuse me for the long answer. It is important to me to keep it working with Vue as for the actual problem, sorry haven't mentioned, move the slider you'll see that only the scale of each pattern element is updated. I end up with deleting and creating all the elements with each parameter change.

Comment: Make it work without vue before trying to get it to work with it.

Comment: I will probably give up with SVG.js no reasons to use it with Vue at the moment.